# Lambda implementation of functional interface returns "unimplemented methods" error - but program works

Tags: java, generics, lambda, interface, functional-interface

I am using eclipse to learn Java generics and lambda basics and I encountered a problem with the implementation of functional interface. I wanted to implement the method via lambda expression, but then compiler constantly shows "The type MyGenericClass must implement the inherited abstract method FunctionalIfce.getType()" even though I implemented it via lambda expression and later on even used in a program. When running there are no problems - all of the results are correct but error persists. Everything is within one package. Here are the implementations:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface FunctionalIfce {
    Type getType();
}
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class MyGenericClass<T extends Number> 
                    implements FunctionalIfce{

    private T value;

    // Lambda implementation of interface
    public FunctionalIfce fIfce = () -> {
        Type parameterType = value.getClass();
        return parameterType;
    };

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The value is equal: "+value+" and it's type: "+fIfce.getType();
    }

    //Stadard implementation ###  Lambda implementation above
    /*
    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        Type parameterType = value.getClass();
        return parameterType;
    }
    */

}
```

And from Main class I call it as followed:

```
    public class AdvancedEntry {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyGenericClass<Integer>  generic = new MyGenericClass<>();
            generic.setValue(5);
            System.out.println(generic.toString());         
        }

    }
```

Is that an eclipse problem or did I make a mistake in my implementation that magically works?
I will really appreciate any help on this puzzle since I found nothing that would remotely look like my issue.

Comment: Your code should never compile as class 'MyGenericClass' must provide an implementation for 'getType()' method. There might be an issue with your eclipse. Can you post your output?

Comment: This is my output: "The value is equal: 5 and it's type: class java.lang.Integer".
Also from what I have read declaring interface and assigning lambda expression, and then using this declaration to obtain method value is a valid implementation of the method. In all of the examples, I've seen it was done within main method.

Comment: You are not implementing FunctionalIfce by MyGenericClass. However, you create a public field there, fIfce, which implements the FunctionalIfce by itself. You still need to override getType in MyGenericClass though.

Comment: If you proper implement FunctionalIfce then you should be able to call getType as generic.getType() in your main class. Not generic.fIfce.getType().

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I see where I made a mistake now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the interface implementation and it works.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class MyGenericClass<T extends Number>{

    private T value;

    // Lambda implementation of interface
    public FunctionalIfce fIfce = () -> {
        Type parameterType = value.getClass();
        return parameterType;
    };

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The value is equal: "+value+" and it's type:    "+fIfce.getType();
    }


    //Stadard implementation ###  Lambda implementation above
    /*
    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        Type parameterType = value.getClass();
        return parameterType;
    }
    */

}
```